# Remove contact from contact list

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets, list-manager

I am trying to remove a contact from a contact list using next code:

```
using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, email);
    var contact = client.Get(reference, new ContactExpandOptions(new string[]
    {
        "ListSubscriptions"
    }));
    if (contact == null) return;

    Guid contactListId = new Guid(ListId);

    IDefinitionManager<IContactListDefinition> manager = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetDefinitionManagerFactory().GetDefinitionManager<IContactListDefinition>();


    var contactList = manager.Get(contactListId, new CultureInfo("en"), true);


    contact.RemoveListSubscriptions(client, true, new Guid[]
    {
        contactListId
    });
    client.Submit();
}
```

I can see the list in the `ListSubscriptions` facet but is not removed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use code like this and it works fine. It is similar to yours however there are some differences:

```
using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    try
    {
        var identifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(IdentifierSources.Email, email);
        var contact = client.Get(identifier, new ContactExpandOptions(ListSubscriptions.DefaultFacetKey));
        var contactList = contact.ListSubscriptions()?.Subscriptions?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ListDefinitionId.Equals(contactListId));

        if (contactList == null)
        {
            return ContactListOperationResultEnum.ContactNotOnTheList;
        }

        var subscriptions = contact.ListSubscriptions();
        subscriptions.Subscriptions.Remove(contactList);
        client.SetListSubscriptions(contact, subscriptions);
        client.Submit();

        return ContactListOperationResultEnum.Success;
    }
    catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Exception during removing contact from list {contactListId}", ex, this);
        return ContactListOperationResultEnum.Error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating in case anyone finds this in the future. I was able to use the subscription service as detailed here: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/the-list-manager-api.html#add-and-remove-contacts

```
var subscriptionService = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISubscriptionService>();
subscriptionService.Unsubscribe(contactListId, contactId);
subscriptionService.Unsubscribe(contactListId, contacts);
```